# What's the meaning of 'project' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from [a news article](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/06/18/asia/police-robots-singapore-security-intl-hnk/index.html) :

> The robots, which have been patrolling the airport since April, are
> meant to “**project** additional police presence” and serve as extra
> “eyes on the ground,” according to the force, which describes them as
> the latest addition to its “technological arsenal.”

I looked up the verb '**project**' in [the OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/project_2).

> 2. to plan an activity, a project etc. for a time in the future
> 3. to present somebody/something/yourself to other people in a particular way, especially one that gives a good impression

I think robots can't plan an activity or a project so '**project**' seems to mean 'to present something to other people in a particular way'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you checked other dictionaries?  I don't think the OLD definitions are very good in this case.  [Merriam-Webster includes "to throw or cast forward : thrust", which seems more applicable.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/project)

Comment: @stangdon You mean 'project (= thrust)' figuratively means '[To extend (a protrusion or appendage) outward](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/project)'. Am I right?

Comment: The definitions in the question aren't very good. "Projecting an image" is normally a bit more forceful than "presenting an image" - it's not literally thrusting out, but it implies active effort and outward engagement, while "present" can be essentially passive.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much.

Comment: @ellse Yes, I think that the robots metaphorically *extend* police presence.

Comment: @stangdon I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The article is using “project” in the sense of trying to present something. The robots are being used to create an impression of enhanced police presence.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The word may be used in the sense of "projection", as in *power or force projection*, that is a term used in military and political science to refer to the capacity of a state to deploy and sustain forces outside its territory.

Comment: Thank you very much.